# Dataloader field mapping

Tags: data-loader

I am using dataloader version 26.0.0 for dataload. I have one scenario where i am inserting account team using dataloader. In csv file, i have all fields for mapping. First i inserted record to account share object with all mappings. Next, when i am going to insert record into account team, fields are missing for mapping so in account team, access levels are set to default. When using newer version of dataloader 37.0.0, i am able to insert record with all mappings.

Can anyone help in this why this is the case with older version of dataloader.
Thanks in advance for your help.

With Older dataloader version-
[image: MApping with older dataloader]
With new dataloader version-
[image: Mapping with new dataloader]

Comment: Based on the thread [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/dataloader/topics/some_custom_fields_in_account_object_not_appearing_in_insert_mapping_window) this could have something to do with a combination of the edition your using, whether those fields are actually visible on the page layout, and the fact you're using an old version of Data Loader. Any reason you need to stick with the old version if the new one is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SFDC schema is versioned. Fields are added over time with each version. If you look at the [Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_accountteammember.htm) for `AccountTeamMember`, you can see that some fields were added in V37.0

1. `CaseAccessLevel`
2. `ContactAccessLevel`
3. `OpportunityAccessLevel`
4. `PhotoURL`
5. `Title`

When you run DataLoader at a specific version level, only the schema fields known to that version are available for CRUD. Hence, unless you run Data Loader at V37.0, these fields can't be updated.

> Update

As for `AccountAccessLevel`, this field, though it existed at V26 is not Createable and hence can't be directly updated by Data Loader. Here's the metadata describe for V26:

[image]

But, in V37, this field is **Createable and Updateable** ! (metadata describe from V37). As to which version it became updateable, you'd have to go through Workbench at each version from 27 onwards until you find it (exercise left to the reader)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time but i can see AccountLevelAccess is also missing in old version of dataloader.   So if these fields are missing in older version of dataloader, is this possible to insert account team member with correct access level using old dataloader?

Comment: @Sofiya,-- see updated answer

Comment: Can you please explain one thing? I want to insert record into AccountTeamMember od some ABC account. For this i am using Older dataLoader. First i inserted record using CSV file into AccountShare object with access levels, userid and accountid. Then i inserted record using same CSV file  into AccountTeamMember object. Team member is added into Account but with default access levels.